# MVC3 FilePathResult and FileStreamResult Replicated Downloads

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, filepath, fileresult

I was reading a great article [here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/125/ASP.NET-MVC-Uploading-and-Downloading-Files) that covers the in's and out's of using ASP MVC for uploading/downloading files. I'll try to keep this short here goes.

My MVC3 app will be running in one place (houston) and its mission will be to allow our employees, all over the world (30 domain controllers) to download various software packages via our Intranet. Today, each of these 30 sites has a replicated "Programs" folder mapped to a shared drive. So, someone in China isn't dowloading an app to install from here in Houston. They'll get if off their logonserver in China. I am able to interrogate the "logonserver" environment variable to determine the server they are on...but short of dynamically building a hyperlink with the UNC embedded (this works by the way)...I can't really use any of the streaming methods specific to MVC because it will end up getting pulled into the box where my web app is running (houston) to be streamed back across some pond. Is my thinking right on this? I prefer to stream because this way I can lock down that Programs folder and only grant the ASP Process the authority to access the replicated folder.